# Submit ios app for review with free apple developer account?

Tags: ios, xcode, submission

Is there any way to add my app for review before paying the $99 fee, with free developer account?

Answer (score 1):

No. You must have a valid developer account with a valid subscription.

https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/